# Sql query to find max value within 60 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table like below (with different ids) ... here for example took `99` ...

```
id  hist_timestamp          DP  mints   Secnds  value
99  2016-08-01 00:09:40     1   9       40      193.214
99  2016-08-01 00:10:20     1   10      20      198.573
99  2016-08-01 00:12:00     1   12      0       194.432
99  2016-08-01 00:52:10     1   52      10      430.455
99  2016-08-01 00:55:50     1   55      50      400.739
99  2016-08-01 01:25:10     2   25      10      193.214
99  2016-08-01 01:25:50     2   25      50      193.032
99  2016-08-01 01:34:30     2   34      30      403.113
99  2016-08-01 01:37:10     2   37      10      417.18
99  2016-08-01 01:38:10     2   38      10      400.495
99  2016-08-01 03:57:00     4   57      0       190.413
99  2016-08-01 03:58:40     4   58      40      191.936
```

Here I have a `value` column, starting from the first record I need to find max value within next 60 seconds which will result in below. In the group of those 60 seconds, I need to select one record with max value.

```
id  hist_timestamp          DP  mints   Secnds  value
99  2016-08-01 00:10:20     1   10      20      198.573
99  2016-08-01 00:12:00     1   12      0       194.432
99  2016-08-01 00:52:10     1   52      10      430.455
99  2016-08-01 00:55:50     1   55      50      400.739
99  2016-08-01 01:25:10     2   25      10      193.214
99  2016-08-01 01:34:30     2   34      30      403.113
99  2016-08-01 01:37:10     2   37      10      417.18
99  2016-08-01 03:57:00     4   57      0       190.413
99  2016-08-01 03:58:40     4   58      40      191.936
```

How to build SQL query to get desired output?

Thanks !!!

Comment: rewrite the question and use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 0):

it's simple. Use `GROUP BY` with `MAX()` function.

Example:

`select max(value) as value
from table
where hist_timestamp between '2016-08-01 00:10:00' and '2016-08-01 00:10:59'
group by value`

This gives you max unique value. Hope it helps

EDIT: if you need more complicated query, like max value for every 60seconds from first date you got in the table, you would need for example recursive `CTE` or more complicated query with `group by`